# How is "int duplicate = num" being used on this snippet?

Tags: c++

I am trying to understand how `int duplicate = num` is being used and also `num = duplicate` at the end of the snippet.

```
int even(int num, ofstream& fileout)  //This function will calculate the even digits
{   int remainder;  //This variable holds the division of the number by 10.
    int reverse = 0;  //This will hold the reverse number.
    bool flag = false;  //Boolean variable.
    int duplicate = num;
    while(num > 0)
    {
        remainder= num%10;
        if((remainder) % 2 == 0)  //This condition will validate equality to zero when divided by 2.  If this is the case ten even numbers
            flag = true;
        num /= 10;
    }
    num = duplicate;
```

Comment: What if you want to use the original value of `num` after the `while` loop?

Comment: You missed out the last lines of the code.

Comment: No one can answer what `num = duplicate;` actually does without the end of the function. It might do absolutely nothing.

Answer (score 2):

duplicate is used to store a copy of num as num is modified in the while loop. Then after the while loop, num is restored from duplicate.

Ordinarily, most folks would just use duplicate in the while loop to avoid having to restore num after the loop.

Comment: thank you so much for your clarification.  Very helpful

Comment: Accept an answer that helped you @CPPapprentice

Answer (score 0):

Because here first duplicate = num
 store the value of num variable into duplicate .
In loop num becomes 0 at the end so we want again num value which stored in duplicate so now num = duplicate ;

Comment: than you so much for assisting me in understanding its use.